# Spring: Should I use @Service and then @Autowired it, OR @Component AnnotationConfigApplicationContext

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, service, autowired

I've got a client class that I want to be able to use anywhere. A singleton would work, I think.

Should I:

**Annotate my client class with `@Service` and then `@Autowired` it anywhere I want it?**

**OR**

**Create a `@Configuration` thingy that has a method that has a `@Bean` to get a new instance of it, and then do the annoying `new AnnotationApplicationContext()` thing to get the context then get my client bean from that?**

I just feel like option 1 is a lot easier and it works, but I get the impression that creating a Bean is the "more correct" way, but I don't understand why - it's definitely not easier. Can someone explain? Is there anything wrong with the first option?

Also, any really, really simplified explanations on what the basic "rules" for this stuff are, would be great if anyone has that up their sleeve..

Thanks

Comment: Option 1. Don't do option 2. This means you are creating a new instance each time you need one, with all the added overhead (if you load a full config you are loading your application each time over and over).

Comment: In most enterprice application the beans are defined using mix of `@Service` annoatation and `@Confuguration` with `@Bean`. My way is i use `@Service` if there will be only one bean for that class, if more than on bean for the class then use `@Bean` and create as many bean as you need.

Answer (score 2):

If you have any dependency jar in your project. If it not a spring project, On that scenario You need to go for `@Bean` definition in your project. **Option 2 - For this case.**

Else If it is a spring project and you have control (write access) on that dependency, u can annotate it with `@Service` and use it by `@Autowired` in your Project. **Option 1 Case**

Answer (score 1):

You should mark your class as `@Component` and `@Autowired` it in the client class.

`@Service` is just a special form of `@Component`

**Example**

```
@Component 
Class AUsefullClass {
  void useFullMethod(){
      System.out.println("ooo");
  }
}

@Controller
Class MyController {

    @Autowired
    AUsefullClass instnceOfaUsefullClass;

    void anyMethod(){
        instnceOfaUsefullClass.useFullMethod();
    }
}
```

Comment: What am I @Autowiring in the client class? I am not sure I follow. I want an instance of the client where I choose, for example in my controller or my service.